# Screening tensor-scalar mechanics with equivalence principle

Tags: gravity, equivalence-principle, modified-gravity

Modified gravity with scalar degrees of freedom generally requires some screening mechanism to pass solar system tests, and that generally breaks down the equivalence principle.

Question: is there any modified gravitational theory that respete the equivalence principle even with some screening mechanism?

Comment: What do you mean by “screening mechanism”?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ST theories that obey the equivalence principle via the use of a screening mechanism. The most common is the so-called Vainsthein mechanism, and is used in Hordeski theory, dRGT spin-0 gravity and DHOST gravity. For an example of DHOST gravity see [Vainshtein regime in Scalar-Tensor gravity: constraints on DHOST theories](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.11591).

Another example of screening is the so-called Chameleon mechanism which protects $f(R)$ theories from deviations, [f(R) Gravity and Chameleon Theories](https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.3415)

The thing we should note is that ST theories typically break the "strong equivalence principle". This difference is key because there is evidence that quantum theories also break this equivalence at certain energies. Thus, if you ST theory that breaks strong equivalence it is does not necessarily mean it needs a full screening mechanism, it may only need an effective screening for low energies.

But for a good example of screening in Gravity, EFTs and such I would recommend googling dRGT gravity. It is the theory of massive gravity that contains no ghosts, and in the decoupling limit it relies on the Vainsthein mechanism to protect the spin-0 part of the theory violating solar system tests. Plus, it also might offer some nice resolutions to the idea of dark energy. It is a very nice, comprehensive example of screening in gravitational theories.